# Flattening rows in Spark along with existing columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing, explode

I have a dataset as below.

```
id1   k1, k2, k3, k4
id2   k1, k2
id3   k2, k3
id4   k4
```

I wish to count the number of rows in which each of my "k" is present along with the id's it is present for.

**output :**

```
k1  2    id1, id2
k2  3    id1, id2, id3
k3  2    id1, id3
k4  2    id1, id4
```

I have used explode and then group by on keys and I get the following output.

```
val newlines = sparkSession.read.textFile(s3Path)
.map(ke => {
            val split = ke.split("\t")
            (split(0), split(1).toString.split(", "))
    })

val myDF = newlines.withColumn("Key", explode($"_3")).groupBy(("Key"))
    .agg(count("Key"))
```

```
k1  2    
k2  3   
k3  2 
k4  2
```

Is there a way I can add id's as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spark inbuilt` functions [**`split,explode,agg`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html)!

***Example:***

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
scala> val df=Seq(("id1","k1,k2,k3,k4"),
                  ("id2","k1,k2"),
                  ("id3","k2,k3"),
                  ("id4","k4"))
              .toDF("a","b")
scala> df.selectExpr("a","explode(split(b,',')) as ex")
         .groupBy('ex) 
         .agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list('a)).alias("b"),
            count("*").alias("cnt"))
         .orderBy('ex)
         .show()
```

***Result:***

```
+---+-----------+---+
| ex|          b|cnt|
+---+-----------+---+
| k1|    id1,id2|  2|
| k2|id1,id2,id3|  3|
| k3|    id1,id3|  2|
| k4|    id1,id4|  2|
+---+-----------+---+
```